# Firebase snapshot has no val attribute

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm kind of new to firebase and I'm running into a problem when I try to retrieve data from the database. My database structure looks like this:

```
/users
-> 12345
    -> name: Jane Doe
    -> email: jane@gmail.com
```

When I try to get the name with the following code, I am not getting a snapshot.val as you can see in the screenshot [image: here]

Here's my code:

```js
firebase.database().ref('/users/12345').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot)
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `snapshot` is a complex object. If you just want to get the JSON value from it: `console.log(snapshot.val())`.

Comment: I tried that. It's returning null

Comment: That means there's no data at the location you're reading. Can you add the JSON of your database (as text, no screenshots) to the question? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to query ids in my realtime database, but I was looking at data in  my cloud firestore and trying to query using one of those ids

Answer (score 1):

You can't get name value just using snapshot. Snapshot is a complex object.

Try this code.

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/12345').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
console.log(snapshot.val()['name'])
});
```

If you want to retrieve any child data then You can pass the attribute name inside [].